# orthonormal set depending on variable

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, orthonormal

Let $A(t) = \{x_1(t), x_2(t),..., x_n(t) \}$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$ where $x_i(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall i$. 
I would like to construct a set $A(t)$ such that

1. $A(t) $ is an orthonormal set, i.e. $x_i(t)^T x_j(t) = \delta_{i,j}$, for all $t$ and for all $i,j \in \{1, 2, ...,n\}$
2. $\forall i: x_i(t)$ is a smooth function and $x_i$ is not constant
3. $\forall i:$ there is no subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $dim(V) < r$ such that $x_i(t) \in V, \forall t$ for $r < n/10$

Are there easy ways to construct such sets?
For $n = 2$ it can be done by 
$$A(t) = \{ \begin{bmatrix}
\sin(t)\\ 
\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
-\cos(t)\\ 
\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix} \}$$
, but I would like to construct it for $n >> 2$

Comment: Why not adapt 5xum's answer by replacing $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ in the n-th pair of vectors by $\sin f_n(t)$ and $\cos f_n(t)$? That would give a lot of room for fulfilling the dimension conditio.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One way that works for even values of $n$ would be to have $$x_1=\begin{bmatrix}\sin t\\\cos t \\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-\cos t\\\sin t \\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\sin t\\\cos t \\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_4=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-\cos t\\\sin t \\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_5=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\\sin t\\\cos t \\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_6=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\-\cos t\\\sin t \\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
and so on.

Comment: In fact, I want that each $x_i(t)$  has a high rank over the parameter $t$. In your example each $x_i(t)$ has rank $2$ . I admit that this was not a condition that was mentioned in the question. I adapt the question

Comment: @Koen What does "rank" mean in this case?

Comment: I adapt the question. See condition 3 in my question